# How to switch env (test, dev, prod) when deploying rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

So where does Rails pick up the environment context (dev, test, prod).

Lets say i am taking my Rails code to a prod server, how do i tell rails to use the prod env file/properties?

Comment: It depends on what appserver you are using in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the environment variable `RAILS_ENV` to `production` or `development`. You can do that through Phusion Passenger's [`RailsEnv`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env) setting (assuming you're using Phusion Passenger, and if you aren't, why aren't you? :) ), or through Apache's `SetEnv` parameter, or using the configuration parameter of whatever server you're running on.

(If you're using Phusion Passenger, `RailsEnv` is set to `production` by default.)

Comment: Because passenger is not a silver-bullet.

Comment: yea i just deployed using passenger. Where can i find RAILS_ENV?

Also does passenger overwrite RAILS_ENV property by default?

Comment: ok sorry got it, i just read "environment variable" - RAILS_ENV. So passenger's RailsEnv directive overide the environment variable